# Plotting multiple lines with a Nested Dictionary, and unknown variables to Line Graph

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, matplotlib, nested, graphing

I was able to find somewhat of an answer to my question, but it was not as nested as my dictionary and so I am really unsure how to proceed as I am still very new to python. I currently have a nested dictionary like

{'140.10': {'46': {'1': '-49.50918', '2': '-50.223637', '3': '49.824406'}, '28': {'1': '-49.50918', '2': '-50.223637', '3': '49.824406'}}}:

I am wanting to plot it so that '140.10' becomes the title of the graph and '46' and '28' become the individual lines and key '1' for example is on the y axis and the x axis is the final number (in this case '-49.50918). Essentially a graph like this:

[image]

I generated this graph with a csv file that is written at another part of the code just with excel:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

The problem I am running into is that these keys are autogenerated from a larger csv file and I will not know their exact value until the code has been run. As each of the keys are autogenerated in an earlier part of the script. As I will be running it over various files called the Graph name, and each file will have a different values for:

{key1:{key2_1: {key3_1: value1, key3_2: value2, key3_3: value3}, key_2_2 ...}}}

I have tried to do something like this:

```
for filename in os.listdir(Directory):
if filename.endswith('.csv'):
    q = filename.split('.csv')[0]
    s = q.split('_')[0]
    if s in time_an_dict:
        atom = list(time_an_dict[s])
        ion = time_an_dict[s]
        for f in time_an_dict[s]:
            x_val = []
            y_val = []
            fz = ion[f]
            for i in time_an_dict[s][f]:
                pos = (fz[i])
                frame = i
                y_val.append(frame)
                x_val.append(pos)

        '''ions = atom
        frame = frames
        position = pos
        plt.plot(frame, position, label = frames)
        plt.xlabel("Frame")
        plt.ylabel("Position")
        plt.show()
        #plt.savefig('{}_Pos.png'.format(s))'''
```

But it has not run as intended.
I have also tried:

```
for filename in os.listdir(Directory):
if filename.endswith('_Atom.csv'):
    q = filename.split('.csv')[0]
    s = q.split('_')[0]
    if s in window_dict:
        name = s + '_Atom.csv'
        time_an_dict[s] = analyze_time(name,window_dict[s])
        new = '{}_A_pos.csv'.format(s)
        ions = list(time_an_dict.values())[0].keys()
        for i in ions:
            x_axis_values = []
            y_axis_values = []
            frame = list(time_an_dict[s][i])
            x_axis_values.append(frame)
            empty = []
            print(x_axis_values)
            for x in frame:
                values = time_an_dict[s][i][x]
                empty.append(values)
                y_axis_values.append(empty)
            plt.plot(x_axis_values, y_axis_values, label = x )
plt.show()
```

But keep getting the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "Atoms_pos.py", line 175, in
>
> plt.plot(x_axis_values, y_axis_values, label = x )   File "/Users/hxb51/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py",
> line 2840, in plot
> return gca().plot(   File "/Users/hxb51/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py",
> line 1743, in plot
> lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]   File "/Users/hxb51/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py",
> line 273, in **call**
> yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)   File "/Users/hxb51/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py",
> line 394, in _plot_args
> self.axes.xaxis.update_units(x)   File "/Users/hxb51/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py",
> line 1466, in update_units
> default = self.converter.default_units(data, self)   File "/Users/hxb51/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/category.py",
> line 107, in default_units
> axis.set_units(UnitData(data))   File "/Users/hxb51/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/category.py",
> line 176, in **init**
> self.update(data)   File "/Users/hxb51/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/category.py",
> line 209, in update
> for val in OrderedDict.fromkeys(data): TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Here is the remainder of the other parts of the code that generate the files and dictionaries I am using. I was told in another question I asked that this could be helpful.

```
    # importing dependencies
import math
import sys
import pandas as pd
import MDAnalysis as mda
import os
import numpy as np
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
################################################################################

###############################################################################
Directory = '/Users/hxb51/Desktop/Q_prof/Displacement_Charge/Blah'
os.chdir(Directory)

################################################################################
''' We are only looking at the positions of the CLAs and SODs and not the DRUDE counterparts. We are assuming the DRUDE
are very close and it is not something that needs to be concerned with'''

def Positions(dcd, topo):
    fields = ['Window', 'ION', 'ResID', 'Location', 'Position', 'Frame', 'Final']
    with open('{}_Atoms.csv'.format(s), 'a') as d:
        writer = csv.writer(d)
        writer.writerow(fields)
    d.close()
    CLAs = u.select_atoms('segid IONS and name CLA')
    SODs = u.select_atoms('segid IONS and name SOD')
    CLA_res = len(CLAs)
    SOD_res = len(SODs)
    frame = 0
    for ts in u.trajectory[-10:]:
        frame +=1
        CLA_pos = CLAs.positions[:,2]
        SOD_pos = SODs.positions[:,2]
        for i in range(CLA_res):
            ids = i + 46
            if CLA_pos[i] < 0:
                with open('{}_Atoms.csv'.format(s), 'a') as q:
                    new_line = [s,'CLA', ids, 'Bottom', CLA_pos[i], frame,10]
                    writes = csv.writer(q)
                    writes.writerow(new_line)
                    q.close()
            else:
                with open('{}_Atoms.csv'.format(s), 'a') as q:
                    new_line = [s,'CLA', ids, 'Top', CLA_pos[i], frame, 10]
                    writes = csv.writer(q)
                    writes.writerow(new_line)
                    q.close()
        for i in range(SOD_res):
            ids = i
            if SOD_pos[i] < 0:
                with open('{}_Atoms.csv'.format(s), 'a') as q:
                    new_line = [s,'SOD', ids, 'Bottom', SOD_pos[i], frame,10]
                    writes = csv.writer(q)
                    writes.writerow(new_line)
                    q.close()
            else:
                with open('{}_Atoms.csv'.format(s), 'a') as q:
                    new_line = [s,'SOD', ids, 'Top', SOD_pos[i], frame, 10]
                    writes = csv.writer(q)
                    writes.writerow(new_line)
                    q.close()
    csv_Data = pd.read_csv('{}_Atoms.csv'.format(s))
    filename = s + '_Atom.csv'
    sorted_df = csv_Data.sort_values(["ION", "ResID", "Frame"],
                         ascending=[True, True, True])
    sorted_df.to_csv(filename, index = False)
    os.remove('{}_Atoms.csv'.format(s))

''' this function underneath looks at the ResIds, compares them to make sure they are the same and then counts how many
 times the ion flip flops around the boundaries'''
def turn_dict(f):
    read = open(f)
    reader = csv.reader(read, delimiter=",", quotechar = '"')
    my_dict = {}
    new_list = []
    for row in reader:
        new_list.append(row)
    for i in range(len(new_list[:])):
        prev = i - 1
        if new_list[i][2] == new_list[prev][2]:
            if new_list[i][3] != new_list[prev][3]:
                if new_list[i][2] in my_dict:
                    my_dict[new_list[i][2]] += 1
                else:
                    my_dict[new_list[i][2]] = 1
    return my_dict

def plot_flips(f):
    dict = turn_dict(f)
    ions = list(dict.keys())
    occ = list(dict.values())
    plt.bar(range(len(dict)), occ, tick_label = ions)
    plt.title("{}".format(s))
    plt.xlabel("Residue ID")
    plt.ylabel("Boundary Crosses")
    plt.savefig('{}_Flip.png'.format(s))

def analyze_time(f, dicts):
    read = open(f)
    reader = csv.reader(read, delimiter=",", quotechar='"')
    new_list = []
    keys = list(dicts.keys())
    time_dict = {}
    pos_matrix = {}
    for row in reader:
        new_list.append(row)
    fields = ['ResID', 'Position', 'Frame']
    with open('{}_A_pos.csv'.format(s), 'a') as k:
        writer = csv.writer(k)
        writer.writerow(fields)
    k.close()
    for i in range(len(new_list[:])):
        if new_list[i][2] in keys:
            with open('{}_A_pos.csv'.format(s), 'a') as k:
                new_line = [new_list[i][2], new_list[i][4], new_list[i][5]]
                writes = csv.writer(k)
                writes.writerow(new_line)
                k.close()
    read = open('{}_A_pos.csv'.format(s))
    reader = csv.reader(read, delimiter=",", quotechar='"')
    time_list = []
    for row in reader:
        time_list.append(row)
    for j in range(len(keys)):
        for i in range(len(time_list[1:])):
            if time_list[i][0] == keys[j]:
                pos_matrix[time_list[i][2]] = time_list[i][1]
        time_dict[keys[j]] = pos_matrix
    return time_dict


window_dict = {}
for filename in os.listdir(Directory):
    s = filename.split('.dcd')[0]
    fors = s + '.txt'
    topos = '/Users/hxb51/Desktop/Q_prof/Displacement_Charge/topo.psf'
    if filename.endswith('.dcd'):
        print('We are starting with {} \n '.format(s))
        u = mda.Universe(topos, filename)
        Positions(filename, topos)
        name = s + '_Atom.csv'
        plot_flips(name)
        window_dict[s] = turn_dict(name)
        continue
time_an_dict = {}
for filename in os.listdir(Directory):
    if filename.endswith('.csv'):
        q = filename.split('.csv')[0]
        s = q.split('_')[0]
        if s in window_dict:
            name = s + '_Atom.csv'
            time_an_dict[s] = analyze_time(name,window_dict[s])
for filename in os.listdir(Directory):
    if filename.endswith('.csv'):
        q = filename.split('.csv')[0]
        s = q.split('_')[0]
        if s in time_an_dict:
            atom = list(time_an_dict[s])
            ion = time_an_dict[s]
            for f in time_an_dict[s]:
                x_val = []
                y_val = []
                fz = ion[f]
                for i in time_an_dict[s][f]:
                    pos = (fz[i])
                    frame = i
                    y_val.append(frame)
                    x_val.append(pos)

            '''ions = atom
            frame = frames
            position = pos
            plt.plot(frame, position, label = frames)
            plt.xlabel("Frame")
            plt.ylabel("Position")
            plt.show()
            #plt.savefig('{}_Pos.png'.format(s))'''
```

Everything here runs well except this last bottom block of code. That deals with trying to make a graph from a nested dictionary. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer:

```
for filename in os.listdir(Directory):
if filename.endswith('_Atom.csv'):
    q = filename.split('.csv')[0]
    s = q.split('_')[0]
    if s in window_dict:
        name = s + '_Atom.csv'
        time_an_dict[s] = analyze_time(name,window_dict[s])
        new = '{}_A_pos.csv'.format(s)
        ions = list(time_an_dict[s])
        plt.yticks(np.arange(-50, 50, 5))
        plt.xlabel('Frame')
        plt.ylabel('Z axis position(Ang)')
        plt.title([s])
        for i in ions:
            x_value = []
            y_value = []
            time_frame =len(time_an_dict[s][i]) +1
            for frame in range(1,time_frame):
                frame = str(frame)
                x_value.append(int(frame))
                y_value.append(float(time_an_dict[s][i][frame]))
            plt.plot(x_value, y_value, label=[i])
            plt.xticks(np.arange(1, 11, 1))
        plt.legend()
        plt.savefig('{}_Positions.png'.format(s))
        plt.clf()
    os.remove("{}_A_pos.csv".format(s))
```

From there, with the combo of the other parts of the code, it produces these graphs:
[image]

For more than 1 file as long as there is more '.dcd' files.
[image]